# How do I setup multiple configs for gitolite - post-receive hook email notification?

Tags: git, email, githooks, gitolite, git-post-receive

I have the post-receive hook running with a configuration in gitolite that emails a group when any files change in a repo on a certain branch.  Now, I have a request to setup email notification for a different "TO" when certain files change in the same repo.  How do I set up multiple configs for the post-receive email hook?  Also, how do I trigger a post-receive hook based on files that changed?  I don't believe the hook has file info, right?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inspect `git log --name-only oldrev..newrev` output to determine if any files that you are interested are changed.

Comment: ok, but how do I configure multiple recipients for different emails?

Comment: There is a gitolite_user variable you can read. Check out the sample hook included in gitolite.

Comment: Thanks Adam, but I am not sure how that helps me?  The TO I need to send to is an email alias, and there are 2 different lists depending on the branch and/or the files modified.

Comment: Also, I tried your command git log ... in my post-receive hook, and it doesn't seem to give any results.  Are you sure I can use a git command in a post-receive hook?